# Label point layer with attribute of surrounding line features (QGIS 3.x)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling

I would like to label the points of my point layer with the name attributes of the surrounding line features. The result should be a list, with the names of all lines next to the point (f.e. 10 map units).
In the screenshot you can see, which result I do expect.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all your line features are on the same layer, try

`aggregate('line_layer_name','concatenate',"line_name_field",intersects($geometry,buffer(geometry(@parent),10)),'\n')`

in the label expression for your point feature.

Change `10` to whatever distance you want to pick up features from, and `\n` to whatever you want to delimit each line name with (comma, full stop, comma+newline...)

2020 update:

[As of QGIS 3.8](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog38/index.html#feature-order-by-support-for-expression-aggregate-and-concatenation-functions) you can order the resulting features by any order you want (alphabetically by `line_name_field`, or by `id`...) by adding it as an extra parameter (`order_field` below):

`aggregate('line_layer_name','concatenate',"line_name_field",intersects($geometry,buffer(geometry(@parent),10)),'\n',"order_field")`

---

As a bonus, another alternative for more complex list scenarios is to use `array_agg` and access the full suite of array functions to slice and dice the list however you want.
For example if you have a very long list and want it to:

- show only distinct values
- be in alphabetical order
- showing just the first 3 and last items

You could use something like this:

```
array_to_string(
        with_variable('label_array',

                      array_sort(array_distinct(  
                                 aggregate('line_layer_name','array_agg',                                                       
                                 "line_name_field", intersects($geometry,
                                 buffer(geometry(@parent),10))))),

                      array_cat(array_slice(@label_array,0,2),
                                array('...',@label_array[-1]))),
        '\n' )`
```

You could then change `array_slice(@label_array,0,2)` to `0,5` or any range you want to easily change the number of items displayed.

[image]